# Paho client limit?

Tags: java, python, mosquitto, paho, microbenchmark

I'm running some performance test of a service/client service using mosquitto broker and clients, and paho clients. I got some strange results:

Deployment notes:

- 3 machines; producer, broker, consumer
- Producers: 6 python scripts using mosquitto_pub as fast they can. See below.
- Consumer: simple java client show below. Subscribing to all topics.
- The hardware specifics has not shown significant difference.

1) Mosquitto gets around 1459.5055 messages/s but it sends only 973.9596666666667. The subscribers just get 485.5458333333333 .

2) Not matter how many instances of the paho clients are created the performance do not improve. E.g. if you run 6 producers in one topic and 2 consumer in two topic you will get 485.5458333333333. But if you add 6 producers to the other topic (already checked that the total amount of messages increment) the total performance stay the same  and per topic is divided by two.

3) If you do the precisely the test to two separated java application the performance do not drop. Each application gets the max performance.

In no case the CPU or memory reaches any limit.

**Producers.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import os,sys,time, json, random, itertools

arg = sys.argv
host="broker"

n=1
if len(arg)>1:
    n = int(arg[1])

i=0
while True :

    payload = {"id":str(n),"Time":datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00Z"),"ResultValue":1.0,"ResultType":"integer","Datastream":{"id":str(n)}}

    os.system( "mosquitto_pub -h "+host+" -t "+("/"+str(payload["id"])+" -m " +str(json.dumps(json.dumps(payload)))+"")
```

**Consumer.java**

```
package eu.linksmart.testing;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Application implements MqttCallback {
    public Application() {
        id++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Application app = new Application();
            create("1",new Application());
            create("2",new Application());

            while (true)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    static void create(String id, Application app) throws MqttException {
        MqttClient mqttClient =  new MqttClient("tcp://broker:1883", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new MemoryPersistence());
        mqttClient.connect();
        mqttClient.subscribe("/"+id+"/#", 1);

        mqttClient.setCallback(app);
    }
    long acc =0;
    int i=0;
    long start= System.nanoTime();
    static  int id=0;
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {

        i++;
        acc = (System.nanoTime()-start);
        if(acc/1000000>1000){
            start = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(String.valueOf((i * 1000000000.0) / acc));
            acc =0;
            i=0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

    }

}
```

E.g. running producer for topic 1 as:

```
python Producers.py 1&
```

What limits the paho client inside an java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of debugging I found out what was the problem.

The topic `$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/1min` was reporting more messages as I was sending. Probably is counting the protocol messages as messages. It is so that in idle this topic is reporting 3.22 with one subscriber. So I thought I was sending 1459.5055 per/sec, this reported by mosquitto. But I was sending just the 485.5458333333333.

So do not trust this topic for application messages payload!